# 'Failed to fetch updates' shows up when I open AppCenter

Tags: updates, appcenter

[image]
'Failed to fetch updates' shows up when I open AppCenter. Can someone tell me how to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

The small black window in the center of your screenshot indicates that you must have manually added at least one non-system repository, which doesn't have proper release file, suitable for your current system (apparently, Ubuntu 18.04 if you're on elementary OS 5).

To solve this issue, you should remove that particular PPA from your system:

1. Right click on **Files** and select **New Window as Administrator**.
2. Go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder.
3. Inside that folder, delete all files that contain `sarimkhan` in their names.
4. Then try running an update via AppCenter.

In case of more errors (the messages that begin with `E:`) post them here.

**#** Or please execute this command bellow in terminal to remove that repository,

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./"
```

Comment: there are no folder named 'etc' there

Comment: @MusabbirKazimNiloy The 'etc' folder is not under your user directory. Please move up to access the directory. Looking at the image attached to your question I can see that the error is due to an outdated repository that does not have a release file for current ubuntu version. Please execute `sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./"` to remove the repository, error will be gone.